# Magick++ not loading TGA blob

Tags: c++, imagemagick

I have a buffer containing the data for an RLE-compressed 8-bit RGB TGA image. I want to load this into a Magick++ Image but I keep getting

```
Magick: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/353
```

Here is my code

```
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::ifstream file("window_borders.tga", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    std::streamsize size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    char* buffer = new char[size];
    if (!file.read(buffer, size)) return 1;

    Magick::Blob data_blob(buffer, size);
    Magick::Image m_image(data_blob);

    return 0;
}
```

If I identify it I get

```
window_borders.tga TGA 330x390 330x390+0+0 8-bit sRGB 33106B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Annoyingly, if I specify this info, then it works just fine. I can even convert it:

```
Magick::Image m_image(data_blob, Magick::Geometry("330x390"), "TGA");

m_image.magick("JPEG");
m_image.write("test.jpg");
```

And indeed `test.jpg` and `window_borders.tga` look identical. Why can't it detect the format automatically?

Comment: It feels hard to tell unless we trace the code with debugger and see why the image `data_blob` is of wrong format?

Comment: See my above edit. I have triple checked that I am feeding the correct data into the blob constructor, somehow the validity of the blob changes depending on some other unknown factor.

Comment: And now `Magick::Image m_image();` is missing `data_blob` parameter?

Comment: Ugh. Yes, I'm an idiot. Well adding in that parameter now my minimal example has the same error.

Comment: It does not identify the sample automatically and probably is a defect of ImageMagick. I would step in that call and see then. The docs use word "usually". "ImageMagick can usually auto-magic-ally detect the image's format."

Comment: Would be interesting to see if ImageMagick has the same issue with other formats -- TGA isn't widely used anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can't it detect the format automatically?

The TGA format never really had a unique "magick-number" header, or some other
quick+reliable way to identify if a TGA exist within a blob.

If I remember correctly, later extended version of TGA introduced the string
`TRUEVISION-XFILE` as a magick identifier, but at the files footer table.

I'm not an expert, but I imagine some software designers would be shaking their
heads.

Now, not only are you responsible for knowing the file format ahead of time
*(by given filename)*, but have to fully & correctly read the image-header
to determine where the image-data stops, and the image-footer starts.

I would guess that this would be a large contributing factor into why there's no
`IsTGA` method like we have [`IsPNG`](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/coders/png.c#L1232), [`IsTIFF`](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/coders/tiff.c#L252), and so on...

As you've previously discovered one solution.

```cpp
Magick::Image m_image(data_blob, Magick::Geometry("330x390"), "TGA");
// This should work too.
Magick::Image m_image(data_blob, Magick::Geometry("0x0"), "TGA");
```

But you can also do the following.

```cpp
Magick::image m_image;
m_image.magick("TGA");
m_image.read(data_blob);
```